# Why does Uri get a special answer when his balloon pops?

Tags: short-stories, hebrew-language, miriam-roth

In Miriam Roth's classic Hebrew children's book *A Tale of Five Balloons* (Hebrew: מעשה בחמישה בלונים), five children each get a balloon:

[image: What fun! What joy! A balloon for every girl and boy!]

In sequence, each child sees their balloon pop. And each is told not to cry, with the refrain, "That's the end of every balloon" -- "זה סופו של כל בלון".

[image]

While this is a very simple children's story, it deals very directly and explicitly with loss and impermanence; possibly even grief.

Which is why I'm always a little unsettled by the *first* iteration, which is a little different -- a small difference, but I feel a significant one. When Uri's green balloon pops, he isn't told to cheer up because "that's the end of every balloon." Instead, he's exhorted:

> אל תבכה, אורי
>   אל תצטער
>   נקנה לך בלון אחר
>
> Don't cry, Uri,
>   Don't be sad
>   **We'll buy you a new balloon**

This is a perfectly reasonable thing to say to a crying young child -- but it feels to me at odds with all the following repetitions. None of the other children are promised another balloon; all of them are told to accept the popping of balloons as inevitable.

**Why is Uri different from all the others?** Isn't it odd to break the story structure in this one, initial instance? Is there thematic significance here; does this somehow tie into the theme?

I welcome both analysis, and any commentary from the author that addresses the question.